# '.blur' input and hide keyboard after pressing return on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a single input field, the form submits when you press enter. This causes the text you have typed to be appended to a table. The input field remains in focus as you may want to enter multiple items, this functionality is only user friendly when on a machine with a physical keyboard.

Using a combination of Angular, Bootstrap and JavaScript, is there anyway to unfocus an input to automatically hide the keyboard after pressing return when entering text into an input box on a mobile device?

I could use jQuery to `.blur()` the input on the return keypress, but I only want this functionality to kick in if you are on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the device is phone or tablet :

```
var width = window.innerWidth;

var height = window.innerHeight;

if(width < 750 && height < 1100) {
    $console.keypressed(function(e) {
        if(e == 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    }
}
```

But $console is my text area :

```
var $console = $('textarea');
```